# Proving a result in maximum likelihood inference

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification

I need help proving a result shown in a paper. I am reading *Assessing the Quadratic Approximation to the Log Likelihood Function in Nonnormal Linear Models* by Salomon Minkin.

The paper defines several concepts that are used in the argument, so I'll state those here:

---

### **Definitions**

Let $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $L(\beta;x)$ be a a log-likelihood function and $\hat{\beta}$ be the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of the parameter $\beta$ given data $x$ ($x$ is a vector of observations)

Let $Q(\beta;\hat{\beta},x)$ be the *quadratic approximation* to $L(\beta;x)$ around the   $\hat{\beta}$ (i.e., the second degree Taylor approximation about $\hat{\beta}$).

The argument uses the "drop" in the loglikelihood functions as you move away from their common maximizer at $\hat{\beta}$

Let $D_L(\beta):=D_L(\beta;\hat{\beta},x)=L(\hat{\beta};x) - L(\beta;x)$ be the drop in the $L$ at point $\beta$.

Similarly, $D_Q(\beta):=D_Q(\beta;\hat{\beta},x)=Q(\hat{\beta};\hat{\beta},x) - Q(\beta;\hat{\beta},x)$ be the drop in the quadratic approximation to $L$ at $\beta$.

---

### Proof Plan

The author then uses $D_L,D_Q$ in the main part of the argument, reproduced below:

[image: Source: https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/70.2.367]

To me it's not clear/obvious that $\beta\in R_L(a_0-d) \implies \beta \in R_Q(a_0) \;\;\forall a_0 \leq a$ so I tried to prove this to myself.

Let's start with $a_0=a$. Here are the series of implications I am trying to prove (there may be a more straightforward approach). The first implication (marked with $(*)$) is the one I'm not sure about, but if I can prove it the rest of the proof here is pretty straightforward. I basically assumed it was true and continued on the proof, now coming back to shore up $(*)$.

$(*): \beta \in R_L(a-d) \implies \beta \in R_A(d)$

$(1): (*) \implies D_Q(\beta) < D_L + d$

$(2): \beta \in R_L(a-d)  \implies D_L(\beta) \leq a - d $

$(3): (2) \wedge (1) \implies D_Q(\beta) < D_L + d \leq (a-d) + d \implies D_Q(\beta) < a$

$(4): (3) \implies \beta \in R_Q(a) \implies R_L(a-d) \subset R_Q(a)$

So, assuming $(*)$ we've shown $\beta \in R_L(a-d) \implies \beta \in R_Q(a)$.

The generalization to $a_0\leq a$ is also straightforward due the definition of $R_Q$. For any decreasing sequence of values $s_1>s_2>s_3...>s_n$ defines a decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ (ellipsoids) $R_Q(s_1)\supset R_Q(s_2)\supset R_Q(s_3)...\supset R_Q(s_n)$

Substituting $a_0 < a$ for $a$ into $(*)$ and proceeding with $(1)-(4)$ gets us the general result stated in the paper:

$$\beta \in R_L(a_0-d) \implies D_Q(\beta) < a_0 \implies \beta \in R_Q(a_0) \implies R_L(a_0-d) \subset R_Q(a_0) \;\;\forall a_0 \leq a$$
$\square$

---

### Proving $(*)$

The jumping off point of my proof is $(*)$, which I am not sure I can rigorously prove.

I feel it needs to use the fact that $R_Q(a) \subset R_A(d)$ and that the regions $R_L(z)$ are connected (as mentioned in the above passage).

**My attempt**

$R_Q(a) \subset R_A(d) \implies |D_Q(\beta)-D_L(\beta)| < d\;\; \forall \beta \in R_Q(a)$ by the definition of $R_A(d)$

To show $R_L(a-d) \in R_A(d)$, there are two cases:

**Case 1:**$R_L(a) \setminus R_Q(a) = \emptyset$

$R_L(a) \setminus R_Q(a) = \emptyset \implies R_L(a) \subset R_Q(a) \implies R_L(a) \subset R_A(d)$.

By the definition of $R_L(z)$, $R_L(a-d) \subset R_L(a) \implies R_L(a-d) \subset R_A(d)$.

**Case 2:**$R_L(a) \setminus R_Q(a) \neq \emptyset$

Let $G = R_L(a) \setminus R_Q(a)$

In this case, we know that $D_L(g) < D_Q(g)\;\;\forall g \in G$:

*Proof*: Assume $g \in G: D_L(g)-D_Q(g) = k > 0$. This means that $D_L(g) = a+k$ which contradicts the fact that $g \in R_L(a)\;\;\;\square$

Since $D_L(g)< D_Q(g)$ over $G$, and also that $R_Q(a) \in R_A(d)$, then $\exists c<d:R_L(a-c) \subset R_Q(a)$. By definition, $R_L(a-d) \subset R_L(a-c) \subset R_Q(a) \subset R_A(d)\;\; \square$

Turns out this appears to simultaneously prove the overall point I was trying to understand.

**Is this correct? Am I missing something?**